# SQL Server 2008 Convert to DateTime error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a nvarchar column which contains dates like this:

```
1 Jul 2010 11:19:22  
18 Jun 2010 9:28:43  
22 Sep 2010 15:22:05
```

These are actually values extracted from a text file. All what I want to do is to convert them to a datetime type. If i try:

```
alter table Table1
alter column MyDateAsString datetime
```

I get: "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string".

I've also tried:

```
select convert(DateTime, MyDateAsString ,112)  from Table1
```

but i get the same error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: create a new column, move data from old column to new column using convert, then delete old column

Comment: Are you sure all the values can be converted? Perhaps there was an error in the text file.

Comment: All of the values (I have only 100) looks valid dates and should be able to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have invalid date values in your table. Try the following.

```
Select (case when isdate(MyDateAsString )=1 then convert(DateTime, MyDateAsString ,112) else  dateadd(year,100,getdate()) end) as dt  from Table1
```

all dates whose year is 2115 has invalid date string in it (Assuming that your system date is correct and there are no normal records in your table whose year is 2115).

Comment: This query returns ALL of my columns as 2115 so the field is not recognized as a date. Wondering if there is still a way to convert them to date..

Comment: The issue was a space at the end of each value: 1 Jul 2010 11:19:22_. Once I've eliminate it, I was able to alter the table: 
ALTER TABLE Test
ADD MyDateAsString DATETIME;. Selecting this answer as correct based on the time and the idea that the data in my table has incorrect values as you mentioned. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Great. LTrim() and RTrim() comes handy in such occassions, especially when there's is a lot of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a column in your table with Datetime data type and then update these values to that column and drop this column and rename that column back to this column .

```
/***        Add a column   **/
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD MyDateAsString_New DATETIME;
GO

/***        Update   **/
UPDATE Table1
 SET MyDateAsString_New = CAST(MyDateAsString AS DATETIME)
WHERE ISDATE(MyDateAsString) = 1   --<-- this will only bring forward 
                                      -- the valid datetime values

/***     Drop Column   **/
ALTER TABLE Table1
DROP COLUMN MyDateAsString;
GO

/***     Rename Column   **/
sp_RENAME 'Table1.[MyDateAsString_new]' , '[MyDateAsString]', 'COLUMN'
GO


Tadaaa
```

Comment: This is a good solution but when I do the update, there are 0 records affected due to all my data being bad (having a space at the end). Appreciate your input-thanks